# Deploying a spring boot legacy webapp to a weblogic 10.3.6 server

Tags: java, deployment, weblogic, spring-boot, weblogic-10.x

I developed a Spring Boot Web-App and need to deploy it to a weblogic 10.3.6 server, so i followed this guide to create a war working on a server with servlet 2.5: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html.

The war i create works on a local weblogic server and on my integrated tomcat-server when i run Application.class.
It does not work on the non-local weblogic server i need to deploy it to.

When i try to start it i get the following exception:

```
   ... Caused By: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/my.package.Application]
    at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getInputStream(ServletContextResource.java:117)...
```

Trying to solve this error i changed my web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:*my.package.Application*</param-value>
</context-param>
```

After this change deploying to the non-local weblogic server and starting the Web-App worked, at least i do not get any exceptions.
However using the url my.weblogic.server:port/deployPath i get a 404 error.(localhost:port/deployPath on my local weblogic, using my original web.xml, the Application works.)

I guess there must be a difference between my local and the non-local weblogic server, but i can't find the one responsible for this behaviour.
I tried to compare the configuration and the jars in the weblogic server folders, but i am not too sure what to look for. A difference i can think of is my local weblogic server runs on windows and the non-local one on linux.

I would appreciate any help and hints on what to look for.

My project strucutre:

```
src 
    |main
        |java
            |demo
        |resources 
            |static
                |resources
                    |css
                        |... my css files
                    |js
                        |... my js files
            |templates
                |my .html (thymeleafe) files
            application.properties      
    |test
        |...
    |webapp
        |WEB-INF
            |web.xml
            |weblogic.xml
pom.xml
```

These are my (original) files:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>my.package.Application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.boot.legacy.context.web.SpringBootContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>metricFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextAttribute</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext.ROOT</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

weblogic.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wls:weblogic-web-app xmlns:wls="http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.4/weblogic-web-app.xsd">
    <wls:weblogic-version>10.3.6</wls:weblogic-version>
    <wls:context-root>/deployPath</wls:context-root>
    <wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
</wls:weblogic-web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>my.groupid</groupId>
    <artifactId>myArtifactId</artifactId>
    <packaging>${packaging.type}</packaging>
    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <packaging.type>war</packaging.type>
           <deploy.path>/deployPath</deploy.path>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
            <version>14</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        ....
     </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/static
                            </directory>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/webapp
                            </directory>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <warName>myName</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:
Changing the entry

```
<param-value>my.package.Application</param-value>
```

to

```
 <param-value>classpath:*my.package.Application*</param-value>
```

was wrong.
Instead adding the Line

```
 <wls:package-name>org.springframework.*</wls:package-name>
```

to my weblogic.xml resolved the issue.

My guess is spring got the wrong classloader from the non-local weblogic server, which was not present on the local one.